# onMouseOver(SomeInt, SomeString) not working

Tags: javascript

I'm creating the following div using javascript, task_id is an int and person_name is a string, why is my alert not working!
when i send 2 integers, the alert works fine, when i send 2 strings the alert still doesn't work, what am i doing wrong?

```
'<div " onMouseOver="Drag(' + task_id + ',' + person_name +');"</div>'
.....


function Drag(id, name){
    alert(id + "   " + name);
}
```

thanks a million in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correctly add escaped string delimiters around the string, otherwise you're sending a variable with the name of `person_name`'s value.  Try:

```
'<div onMouseOver="Drag(' + task_id + ',\'' + person_name +'\');"></div>'
```

Comment: thanks a million, i tried \" instead of \' and it obviously didn't work, i'm still a beginner...

Comment: @Lina: You can't use the same string delimiter as the HTML attribute you're defining.  If your attribute uses double quotes, your inner javascript must use single quotes (apostrophes) and vice versa.